# Error in a Mule application when calling a stored procedure in SQL

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-connector

I want to call a stored procedure but I'm getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@P0'

This is the stored procedure:

[image]

Here is the stored procedure call:

```
{CALL sp_Insert_RiskEvent((:householdId), (:loyaltyCard), (:userId), (:deviceId), (:eventDate), (:eventType))}
```

These are the parameters that I'm sending:

```
{
    'householdId': payload.householdId,
    'loyaltyCard': payload.loyaltyCard default null,
    'userId': payload.userId default null,
    'deviceId': payload.deviceId,
    'eventDate': payload.eventDate,
    'eventType': payload.eventType
}
```

Also I did a typeOf check and here is the response:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFvFj.png)

This is the stored procedure from SQL:

[image]

What is strange is when I add manually in the stored procedure the values the stored procedure is run without any issues.

Here are the answers:

1:

```
{
  "HouseholdId": 1234,
  "LoyaltyCard": 123456,
  "UserId": "6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA",
  "DeviceId": "1234455",
  "EventDate": "2023-02-27T04:00:00Z",
  "EventType": "test"
}

2.
   <flow name="post:\event" doc:id="6a6a8c9a-b430-44d5-ad6e-c31a3a703ff3" >
       <db:stored-procedure doc:name="Stored procedure" doc:id="155e219c-93b4-4a35-976b-2aaba060a8db" config-ref="Database_Config">
           <db:sql ><![CDATA[{CALL sp_Insert_RiskEvent((:HouseholdId), (:LoyaltyCard), (:UserId), (:DeviceId), (:EventDate), (:EventType))}]]></db:sql>
           <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[{
   'HouseholdId': payload.householdId,
   'LoyaltyCard': payload.loyaltyCard default null,
   'UserId': payload.userId default null,
   'DeviceId': payload.deviceId,
   'EventDate': payload.eventDate,
   'EventType': payload.eventType
}]]]></db:input-parameters>
       </db:stored-procedure>
   </flow>
</mule>
```

3:

```
<dependency>            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>        
</dependency>        
<dependency>            
<groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>            <artifactId>mule-db-connector</artifactId>            <version>1.13.5</version>            
<classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>        
</dependency>
```

4:
7.11.1

5:
6.2.2.jre8

Comment: It can be because of the name of the store procedure, which has underscores?

Comment: questions: 1) share the values of the actual arguments that the flow is sending to the operation. 2) instead of screenshots of the operations share the XML of the **full** operation from the flow. Don't use screenshots in Stackoverflow for things that can be shared as text. 3) Version of the Mule Database connector? 4) Version of Mule? 5) Database engine name and version? 6) JDBC driver and version?

Comment: @aled I added the details in the description, please let me know if there are any info that I can provide. Thanks

Comment: You should add the information but not referencing the numbers in my comment. Your question should be readable and contain the needed information. Still missing version of Mule and the Mule Database Connector.

Comment: Did you try removing the parentheses around the arguments in the stored procedure call?

Comment: @aled, I've tried that and now is working, thanks

Comment: Posted it as an answer so it can be accepted

Comment: I recommend to accept the answer as a signal to other users that it is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the parentheses around the parameters. They are redundant and may confuse the SQL parser.